# Details, We're sorry, but the Customer-Supplied Encryption Key feature is not available in your location

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I tried to use my own key to encrypt the data to the Google Cloud Storage service and got that error. I choose US-Central as location for the server. Dont' get it.

Exact message:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 AccessDenied: [(Details, We're sorry, but the Customer-Supplied Encryption Key feature is not available in your location)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The Customer-Supplied Encryption Key feature is restricted by country:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption#general_restrictions

It's based on where you're making the request. What country are you in?

Comment: Oh come on! I'm from Argentina. I'll fill up the request form, but... sheez.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla - any reason the default encryption doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes. It's like lending my house keys to a neighbour and request them every time i want to enter. One day i'll find my home empty because he lost it, misused it or gave it away to "legal authorities" under foreign laws (as stated, i'm from Argentina).

Comment: CSK is a nice feature, but if you are very concerned about that class of problem, you may wish to consider encrypting your data locally before uploading it to GCS, then decrypting it locally after retrieving it. Under that model, Google would never have access to your keys or your unencrypted data at any point, and so you would not be required to trust the service at all.