# Upload to bucket with customer-managed encryption fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-kms

Based on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-managed-keys

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create key ring and key in Cloud KMS in a specific location
   (us-central-1 for example).
2. Grant permission Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter to the storage service account for the created key.
3. Create a new regional bucket in the location (us-central-1) and set created KMS key for encryption.
4. Try to upload a file to the bucket.

Result:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "We're sorry, but the Cloud KMS encryption feature is not available in your location; see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys#restrictions for more details."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "We're sorry, but the Cloud KMS encryption feature is not available in your location; see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys#restrictions for more details."
 }
}
```

I'm quite sure it is a misconfiguration issue but couldn't figure out my mistake. The request goes not from restricted country - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption#general_restrictions

Comment: Do any of the restrictions listed in the link apply to you? From the error message, it seems you are trying to use Cloud KMS from a restricted country.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Details, We're sorry, but the Customer-Supplied Encryption Key feature is not available in your location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129410/details-were-sorry-but-the-customer-supplied-encryption-key-feature-is-not-av)

Comment: I'm not in India or Brazil

Comment: From what country are you calling the API?

Comment: I'm calling it from Ukraine

Comment: As mentioned on this page, CMEK are not able to be called in that region: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys#restrictions

Comment: @sethvargo thanks for help